# Angular Signal computed functionality doesn't update the number of item an array contain

Tags: angular, angular-signals

I have this service

```
itemList= signal<Item[]>([]);
reset(){
   this.itemList.set([]);
}
add(item){
 this.itemList.update(list => {
  const ind = list.findIndex(o => o._id == item._id);
  if (ind !== -1) {
    list.splice(ind, 1);
  } else {
    list.push({_id:item._id,name:item.name});
  }
  list.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name === b.name ? 0 : -1);
  return list;
})
}
itemCount = computed(() => this.itemList().length);
```

reset function and add item is working as expect but the itemCount is not updating, it is always ZERO.

I tried by accessing the service directly in the html : `service.itemCount()` and it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong ?

However, if I use `service.itemList().length` it works.

**UPDATE**

Please find the issue with angular 17 [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvntvw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't change the reference, angular will assume the value hasn't changed, and won't update

Just change your return value on update to return a new value

```
return [...list];
```

Comment: There is an open issue in github related to this : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53118#event-11039029255

Answer (score 0):

Caio is correct: there was a last-minute change to the signals API that made in-place mutations no longer work. For a more detailed answer, you can [see my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77453610/angular-17-dependent-signal-change-not-detected).